# Properties v method variables

Tags: php

new PHP OOA and have two related questions:

```
class foo {
    private $string = null;
    private $some_trivial_flag = false;

    1)public function help_doing_some_stuff() {

    2)*public function help_doing_some_stuff($some_trivial_flag)* {

         if(!$this->some_trivial_flag(..) ...
    }

public function do_some_stuff() {
    1)  $this->help_doing_trivial_stuff(); 
    2)  *$this->help_doing_trivial_stuff$($this->some_trivial_flag);*    
    }
}
```

or

```
class foo {
   private $string = null;

   public function help_doing_some_stuff($some_trivial_flag) {
      if(!$this->some_trivial_flag(..) ...
   }

  public function do_some_stuff() {
     $some_trivial_flag = false;
     $this->help_doing_trivial_stuff($some_trivial_flag);
  }
```

Is it best to declare every variable used inside a class as a property or keep some declared in the class methods.
Also if you have declared it as a property should you still list in the the 
methods parameter list?

Comment: That's too abstract. Is that a flag that you actually could want to override for some method calls? Or is it an actual object state? Otherwise it seems you are writing an utility class, in which case the flag might better be always and only a parameter.

Comment: @mario - It is a utility class, it's a parser for a translator.

Answer (score 0):

Declare as member variables those variables whose state you need to retain between member function calls.

That's it.

The choice of what variables you accept as parameters to functions is completely unrelated.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the prompt response. Got you on the first bit but what I actually meant by the parameters part is - if it is a class property should you still list it in the parameter list, adding clarity to the function, or just leave the parameter list as () - accessing the var inside the method using $this->thevar.

Comment: @jack: As I said, the two are unrelated. A function parameter has _nothing to do_ with member variables. What you're talking about is creating a _separate_, local variable inside the function that has the same name as a member, just for "clarity"? What would that variable do? What would it mean?